# convert secs to dd:hh:mm:ss (sql:query jsp)

Tags: mysql, jsp

My simple brain is having trouble in determining which changes I need to make to this (which is working)

```
SELECT Name, Zone, Duration,

FLOOR(Duration/3600) as hours

,ROUND(FLOOR((Duration/3600-FLOOR(Duration/3600))*60)) as mins

,ROUND((((Duration/3600-FLOOR(Duration/3600))*60) - FLOOR((Duration/3600-FLOOR(Duration/3600))*60)) * 60) as secs

from duration
```

(Duration is in seconds)

to determining dd:hh:mm:ss (days:hours:minutes:seconds). I know the days calculation needs to divide by 86400 but am not sure what the other calculations should then be.

Assistance appreciated.

Note, after many days of fiddling, this is the closest I can get to something meaningful (without any errors, NULLS etc)

```
SELECT Name, Zone, Duration,
FLOOR(Duration/60/60/24) as days
,FLOOR(Duration/60/60)%24 as hours
,FLOOR(Duration/60)%60 as mins
,Duration%60 as secs
from duration
```

but it would be nice to display everything as 2 characters (dd:mm:hh:mm, not d:hh:m:ss etc) but not by having to use c:set, fmt then c:out etc (which is messy and long in my opinion)

Regards
Ralph

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT Duration DIV 86400, SEC_TO_TIME(Duration MOD 86400)
```

To get the whole thing in one text string, do this:

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS(':', Duration DIV 86400, SEC_TO_TIME(Duration MOD 86400))
```

`DIV` and `MOD` are integer operators. `CONCAT_WS()` concatenates with a specified separator character, `:` in your case.

If for some reason `CONCAT_WS()` doesn't work, try

```
SELECT CONCAT(Duration DIV 86400, ':',SEC_TO_TIME(Duration MOD 86400))
```

It's possible your `Duration` value has a datatype other than `INT`. Try this:

```
SELECT CONCAT(CAST(Duration AS INT) DIV 86400, 
              ':',
              SEC_TO_TIME(CAST(Duration AS INT)  MOD 86400));
```

Comment: Thanks O Jones, your first line works but the second produces NULL, a shame since that would have got around the 838 hour limit of SEC_TO_TIME. I couln't ever get CONCAT or CONCAT_WS to work.

Comment: Strange. I did test this stuff on my server. What version of MySQL do you use?

Comment: Thanks again, did try your CONCAT's though the first produces NULL and the second a syntax error at 'INT'. Granted my MySQL is ancient (5.1.36).. I have edited my original post, I have got somewhere close to what I wanted to achieve.